Logic App - Workflow ManagedIdentity Configuration Invalid
Im trying to fix the issue in my workflow but cant manage it. I will try to describe a set up in details.
I have made my storage account private under the Vnet using private endpoints. Since I have the consumption plan for my logic apps I have whitelisted logic app on my storage account this way:

Then in my logic app I have activatged the system assigned identity and OBJ ID has Storage Blob Data Contributor role on my storage account.
Then I have change my API connection and switched to authenication to managed identity

Then I tired to change the connection in side my Get blob content activity 
But when I save Im getting this error:

Workflow validation failed for the workflow ''.
{"error":{"code":"WorkflowManagedIdentityConfigurationInvalid","message":"The
workflow connection parameter 'azureblob' is not valid. The API
connection 'azureblob' is configured to support managed identity but
the connection parameter is either missing 'authentication' property
in connection properties or authentication type is not
'ManagedServiceIdentity'."}}


I had two blob activity, I failed to made the changes to second to switch managed identity. after that it worked. So above is correct.
